# #NAME? Error when assigning a variable to Label of Shape Data field

Tags: vba, visio

In Visio Professional 2016, I'm trying to assign a string variable, which is a field from a ComboBox, to the label of a newly created row in the Shape Data.

The code first checks if the field already exists and displays a Message Box if this is the case. If not, the code will create a new row in the Shape Data. Adding the Name works fine, as can be seen in this line.

```
vsoShape.Section(visSectionProp).Row(intNewPropRow).NameU = dataType
```

However, when I try to add the Label, I get a #NAME? error.

```
vsoShape.CellsSRC(visSectionProp, intNewPropRow, visCustPropsLabel).FormulaU = dataType
```

The input variable dataType is just a regular string. I've included the full function below. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub AddDataToSelectedShape(dataType As String)

Dim vsoShape As Visio.Shape

Set vsoShape = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.PrimaryItem
    If (vsoShape.CellExistsU("Prop.dataType", fExistsLocally) = True) Then
        MsgBox ("The field is added already.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If (vsoShape.CellExistsU("Prop.dataType", fExistsLocally) = False) Then
        intNewPropRow = vsoShape.AddRow(visSectionProp, visRowLast, visTagDefault)
        vsoShape.Section(visSectionProp).Row(intNewPropRow).NameU = dataType
        vsoShape.CellsSRC(visSectionProp, intNewPropRow, visCustPropsLabel).FormulaU = dataType
        vsoShape.CellsSRC(visSectionProp, intNewPropRow, visCustPropsType).FormulaU = "0"
        vsoShape.CellsSRC(visSectionProp, intNewPropRow, visCustPropsFormat).FormulaU = ""
        vsoShape.CellsSRC(visSectionProp, intNewPropRow, visCustPropsLangID).FormulaU = "1033"
        vsoShape.CellsSRC(visSectionProp, intNewPropRow, visCustPropsCalendar).FormulaU = ""
        vsoShape.CellsSRC(visSectionProp, intNewPropRow, visCustPropsPrompt).FormulaU = ""
        vsoShape.CellsSRC(visSectionProp, intNewPropRow, visCustPropsValue).FormulaU = ""
        vsoShape.CellsSRC(visSectionProp, intNewPropRow, visCustPropsSortKey).FormulaU = ""
        Application.EndUndoScope UndoScopeID1, True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Visio shapesheet formula formatting can be tricky. In this case, you need to wrap your `dataType` variable in single quotes in order to store that value as the label and prevent your sub-function from failing quietly.

Try changing the line in question to this:

```
vsoShape.CellsSRC(visSectionProp, intNewPropRow, visCustPropsLabel).FormulaU = """" & dataType & """"
```

Comment: Also of note: If you are calling this function as a result `EventDblClick` or `EventDrop` then `vsoShape as Visio.Shape` needs to be the first parameter of the subfunction in order for `CALLTHIS()` to work.

Comment: Thank you, this is working. However, I'm not quite sure why I have to use this formatting instead of just using dataType in the line above.

Comment: @LTIgaming To be honest, I'm not entirely sure myself, but I think it has to do with the distinction between `Formula` and `FormulaU`. Because `FormulaU` forces universal syntax (fixed delimiters, etc), it seems to be pickier about having the quotation marks present in the string. You could try your original method with `Formula` and see if that works.